# Best way to start learning Corona?

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I know I know this has been posted millions of times but I still can't find a solution.

I want to start learning Corona and taking it seriously but I don't know how to start.

I feel shame actually because I've been playing with its API for a couple of days but I still have lots of weakness and questions mostly in its basics and structure of the language.

People posted Lua online Book link but how to start with it? Do I have to download Lua compiler or I could just use Corona compiler and after a fast checking I feel there is difference between lua and corona when it comes to syntaxes.

I've never felt this way when I started learning Fortran75 and Java. Everything was easy to look for books (love books) and videos and much more.

So to all Corona expert lvls please guide me to the best road to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://www.learningcorona.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn using the Corona SDK, have a look at http://www.learningcorona.com as proposed by jhocking.

If you want to learn Lua first, check out http://lua-users.org/. You will find tutorials and code snippets there, which should get you started.

Another good starting point to learn Lua is to look at the rosetta code site: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Lua There you can compare Lua to one of the languages you already know.

Last but not least, I would be happy to help you myself, if you ask more specific questions.

I have written a complete tutorial on my blog http://www.cutemachine.com on how to write a complete game with the Corona SDK. It is also listed on learningcorona.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have less Corona experience than you (zero), but have you googled:

[Corona Dev Platform Tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=Corona+dev+platform+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

The first 6 or so are really promising looking.

Comment: Thank you. I googled hundreds of times and I also read and implemented tutsplus tutorials, but I still don't think this is right :S

Comment: What don't you think is "right"? You don't find it helpful? Or you think the tutorials are flat out wrong?

Comment: Hmmm... I think it is not so much helpful :S

Comment: I think you're going to have to ask a more specific question then. Sorry! Hope you find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn about corona sdk visit this followed link , this will helpful for you , http://docs.coronalabs.com/
This tutorial provide by Corona lab.