# 2d Mobile Gaming

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-iphone, unity-game-engine, coronasdk

I'm looking to create a 2d mobile game (iPhone and Android). Are there any resources that you're aware of that breakdown the following in depth (yes, I googled it):

- Corona SDK
- Cocos 2d
- Unity
- GameSalad

As a little background, I've been doing iOS programming for ~2 years.

Comment: Have you gone to see almighty overlord [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=ios+game+development&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=fr&client=safari)?

Comment: I'm looking for a concrete side-by-side breakdown and comparison of all 4. As I mentioned in my post, I've googled it. 
Probably best not to post if you don't have a decent answer.

Comment: it's also probably not best to lecture me as to the etiquette of a website you've chosen to post a question that has been asked a [million](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249882/best-way-to-start-learning-corona) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289388/how-to-implement-cocos2d) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070083/how-well-does-unity-3d-work-for-both-android-and-iphone).  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Maybe add Cocos2D-x to that list if you are interested in Android.  http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

Answer (score 4):

You obviously haven't done enough research for your question, as googling [corona cocos2d unity](http://www.google.com/search?q=corona+cocos2d+unity&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=fr&client=safari) pulls up [a simply excellent comparison of not 3, but 6 game engines](http://www.burtonsmediagroup.com/blog/2010/06/game-engines-for-iphone-ipad-android-cocos2d-corona-torque-unity-3d/).  All credit to the author at Burton's media group for this masterpiece.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for (minus GameSalad). Thanks for all your wonderful help!

Comment: My pleasure.  Overlord google knows how to give the right answers, you just have to input the right keywords.  Remember to upvote and accept, and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Cocos2d, as it is, in my opinion, equally or even better than Corona, and it is free.

Some great resources to get you starting off are thenewboston's video series, which start off as an introduction to cocos2d, and then how to make an RPG. It is a really nice introduction to cocos2d, and helps you understand the programming language. (I am not sure what programming languages you already know)
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL452AE69EA1EAC535

Have fun